# TXT connectivity issue

Tags: excel, vba

I Have recoded a code using the Record button.
Basically, I need to remove all special characters using 65001 in File Origin.

I have run a script that converts the .txt in 65001 formats and applies Text to columns as well. Because I need to open .txt data in an excel file

But the problem is the script is run perfectly fine for the 1st TXT file but But for the remaining .txt Text to column function doesn't apply.

```
 Str = "TEXT;" & myFile
            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Str, destination:=Range("$A$1"))
                .Name = "UK"
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
                .TextFilePlatform = 65001
                .TextFileStartRow = 1
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
                1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
            End With
```

I don't know the exact issue. Please find the attahced image as well the formating of 1st and the remainging txt data in excel file.[image: 1st txt data into excel format]

[image: Remain txt data in excel]

As you can see in 1st image there is noting after the heading "Letest deleivery date". But for the remain format there are data not perfectly extracted from txt to excel.

Please check and let me know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're always adding a new querytable, try removing any existing ones first.

```vb
Dim Str
Str = "TEXT;C:\Tester\tmp.txt"

'remove any existing querytable(s) and clear associated range
Do While ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Count > 0
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1)
        Debug.Print "Clearing querytable at ", .ResultRange.Address
        .ResultRange.Clear
        .Delete
    End With
Loop

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Str, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "UK"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells 'this is better I think
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot for your help buddy